# How to set a conditional breakpoint when the content of the pointer meets the condition?

Tags: gdb

Let's say X0 is a pointer, 0x98765432.

At 0x98765442(0x98765432 + 0x10), it has the value, "abcd efgh".

How do I set a conditional breakpoint to break when 0x98765442 has the value, "abcd efgh"?

something like this?

```
br *0x98765442 if $x0+0x10=="abcdefgh"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `br *0x98765442 if $x0+0x10=="abcdefgh"`

The proposed syntax will not work, because it will compare address of strings (with the right-hand string being "injected" into the process by synthesizing a call `strdup("abcdefgh")`) in the inferior (being debugged) process (and worse, a *different* synthesized string will be generated every time the condition is evaluated).

You want something like:

```
br *0x98765442 if 0 == strcmp((char*)$x0 + 0x10, "abcdefgh")
```